# Математические выражения на языке паскаль: Abs, Exp, Power

Tags: математика, pascal

[image: функции]

Как это записать в паскале?  И правильно ли:

```
a1 <> (1,78 * (sqr(10) * 10) / c2 + c3
(15,22 b) + (1 / (0,5 y))
exp(x - 1) * (abs(sqr(x)) + power(x, 1 / 3)
```

Comment: Скобки. Знак умножения обязательно. Power для куба.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде несколько ошибок, основные из
которых — использование запятой в качестве
разделителя десятичных дробей (в паскале это точка) и неявное умножение
(нету в паскале).  Кроме того, вы не указали диалект паскаля.  Вот
программа без инициализации переменных на диалекте
*Free Pascal*:

```pascal
PROGRAM Main;

USES
    Math;

VAR
    a1, b, c2, c3, g, x: Real;

BEGIN
    { TODO(you):  Initialise all variables.  }

    WriteLn(a1 <> (1.78 * Math.Power(10, 3)) / (c2 + c3));
    WriteLn(15.22 * b + 1 / (0.5 * g));
    WriteLn(Exp(x - 1) * Abs(Sqr(x)) + Math.Power(x, 1 / 3));
END.
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нужны скобки в знаменателе и число лучше просто в научной нотации записать с точкой вместо запятой

```
a1 <> 1.78Е3 / (c2 + c3)
```

Здесь знаков нет и про знаменатель снова забыли

```
15.22*b +  1 / (0.5*gamma)
```

Последнее верно (abs излишнее для квадрата, но раз уж есть в записи...)